# How can I use PyQt 4.x in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'd like to know how I can use PyQt 4.x in Python 3.4.4 on Windows XP(32bit).

I tried installing PyQt4-4.11.3-gpl-Py3.4-Qt4.8.6-x32.exe from [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.3/) page.

I can command `import PyQt4` and it doesn't show any error, but I can't import or use anything else. For example,

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QAxContainer import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
```

engenders only `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found` error.

Is Python 3.4.4 not compatible to PyQt4-4.11.3? I hope to get some help with it.

Comment: Have you tried installing the Wheel package from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4) instead?

Comment: @FernAndr  Thank you for the reply! I downloaded it and tried `python.exe -m pip install PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl`, but after the installing and restarting Python, it still shows `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found` message.

Comment: If you are in windows maybe you should add path to windows path too

Comment: check pyqt modules for `required` word, you got multiple sources!